# How to return a multipart/form-data format message from a Jersey web service

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I've found several examples of how to **consume** multipart POSTs to Jersey, but not how to **produce** this format.

I'm in the process of translating an Apache Wink web service to Apache Jersey (2.25). Both are JAX-RS 2, but I've found some special constructs that exist in Wink that are a challenge to find equivalents for in Jersey.

Since the API is essentially a contract between my service and existing clients, I want to return the same format with Jersey that the service returns now.

The Wink method looks like this (I tried to simplify it a bit):

```
@POST
@Path("download")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, ApiConstants.MEDIA_TEXT_XML_UTF8,
      ApiConstants.MEDIA_APPLICATION_XML_UTF8})
@Produces({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
public Response getFiles(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders, MyFileManifest manifest)
      throws IOException, PermissionDeniedException {

 String boundary = "boundary-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();

  // ... Creates this Wink construct ...

  BufferedOutMultiPart mpEntity = new BufferedOutMultiPart();

  for (int i = 0; i < manifest.getFiles().size(); ++i) {
    MyManifestEntry entry = manifest.getFiles().get(i);
    OutPart op = new OutPart();
    op.addHeader("Name", "file-" + Integer.toString(entryIndex));
    String disposition = "file; filename=\"" + content.partialPath.replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
    op.addHeader("Content-Disposition", disposition);
    op.addHeader("Content-Type", content.contentType);
    op.setBody(fileBlob);
    mpEntity.addPart(op);
  }

  ResponseBuilder rBuild = Response.status(Status.OK).entity(mpEntity)
    .header(ApiConstants.OPEN_DATA_KIT_VERSION_HEADER, ApiConstants.OPEN_DATA_KIT_VERSION)
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  return rBuild.build();

}
```

How can I do this with Jersey?  I found the documentation for the Jersey [FormDataMultiPart](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html?org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataMultiPart.html) class but it doesn't sound like it is intended for returning data.

Comment: Check this link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_multipart_formdata_from_html.html